# convert numpy-C array to C double* [] and back

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy

After a long struggle I managed to succesfully import a numpy array into C, as well return an empty numpy array back with the same size. Now I would like to perform a convolution with a given 3x3 kernel. I am used to create a second C function which performs the operation, while the callable function from python just converts the input arguments to pass them to the function. so what I would like to do is:

1. receive the numpy array from python
2. convert it to a C-double array
3. perform the convolution (leave this to me for now)
4. convert the convoluted array back to C-numpy array
5. return the C-numpy array back to python.

So step 1 and 5 already done. code:

```c
static PyObject *CPtest_convolute(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyArrayObject *in_array;
    PyObject *out_array;

    /*extract input array, create output array*/
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyArray_Type, &in_array))    return NULL;

    /*convert numpy to double*[]*/
    /*convArr = convolute(in_array, kernel);*/

    out_array = PyArray_NewLikeArray(in_array, NPY_ANYORDER, NULL, 0);
    if (out_array == NULL)
        /*for now, i am not going to throw an error, instead return 0.
          python can use that 0 to throw the error */
        return Py_BuildValue("i", 0); 

    /*convert convArr to out_array*/

    return out_array;
};
```

further notes, I use Python 2.7 on Windows 8. the PyMODINIT_FUNC and PyMethodDef are properly initialize (which means, no errors and correct results). While I have found multiple results, they all used things like ctypes or SWIG, not C. Although I am somewhat new in C, I am familiar with the basics (from Arduino C).

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not doing all this in python directly?

Comment: @JulienBernu, because python is a 'very slow' language. simple comparison codes I wrote resulted in that the same code written in C is about 200 times faster than in python. I want to perform a convolution over an 2592x1944 image, huge loops with simple tasks. the program is intended to perform real-time image operations. 1-2 seconds for just the convolution is just too long

Comment: native python is slow, yes (although not always), but numpy is pretty much same as C, and you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @JulienBernu, indeed. I do have to mention that I use numpy for as good as everything. But I already found out that both PIL and the opencv libraries have a "convolution" function (cant say if this is really convolution but results show the same). where my (with numpy) python convolution took 2.7 seconds. the opencv one did it in 0.75 seconds. which is nice, can be done better maybe but for now its nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can get a pointer from numpy array by calling (in python):

```
arr.__array_interface__['data']
```

Be aware of stribes, though.

Given a c-buffer you can construct numpy array via `numpy.frombuffer` function:

```
arr = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype, size, offset=0)
```

(I assume you create new read-write buffer via python or its C API and than use it to store results of computation)

Comment: Ok, I've never though of using pointers (because, I didnt know that they exists). But how do i use the pointer to get the array in C? the pointer is only a integer of the memory location, simply writing something like double array[500] = &43058432; doesnt work right?